# Validation not working for checkbox in angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, checkbox

Validation not working for checkbox.

When checkbox is not selected, form is getting submitted. Also not showing error.

**HTML Code**

```
<form [formGroup]="feedbackFormWithArray" (ngSubmit)="submitData()">
  <label class="form-control-label"><span class="text-danger">*</span>Recommendation:</label>
  <div class="recommendation-div">
    <div class="rec-div" *ngFor="let recommendation of recommendations">
      <label class="container">{{recommendation.listTypeValueName}}
        <input formControlName="recommendation" type="checkbox" value="{{recommendation.listTypeValueId}}"
               [checked]="recommendation.selected" (change)="isAllSelected(recommendation)" />
        <span class="mark"></span>
      </label>
      <div *ngIf="(submitted && recommendation.invalid)">
        <small *ngIf="recommendation.errors?.required" class="text-danger">Please select recommendation</small>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

**TS Code**

```
import { Validators } from '@angular/forms';

submitted : boolean  = false;

this.feedbackFormWithArray= this.fb.group({
  recommendation: ['', [Validators.required]]
});

submitData() {
  this.submitted = true;
}

get recommendation()
{
  return this.feedbackFormWithArray.get('recommendation');
}
```

How to solve this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think replace feedbackForm with feedbackFormWithArray in 3 rd line of ts code

Comment: Did not help @Mithra

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Validators } from '@angular/forms';

submitted : boolean  = false;
//in reactive form you should take care the form controller's name.
this.feedbackFormWithArray= this.fb.group({
  recommendation: ['', [Validators.required]]
});

submitData() {
  this.submitted = true;
}

get recommendation()
{
  return this.feedbackFormWithArray.get('recommendation');
}
```

Comment: Please include a brief explanation of [how and why this solves the problem](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/13138364). This will help future readers to better understand your solution. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-answers/33843884)

Answer (score 0):

There is a static property in class Validators called "requiredTrue".

```
this.feedbackFormWithArray= this.fb.group({
    recommendation: ['', [Validators.requiredTrue]]
});
```

@description
Validator that requires the control's value be true. This validator is commonly used for required checkboxes.

You can check more about it here https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators